# Basic use of `sinatra/websocketio` gem

Tags: ruby, websocket, sinatra

I am trying to use [`sinatra/websocketio`](https://github.com/shokai/sinatra-websocketio) gem and I basically copy-pasted their from their README and I can't get it to work. Am I missing something? I think socket port and Sinatra port should be the same. I appreciate any help or hint.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var io = new WebSocketIO().connect();
    // io.on("log", function(value) {
    //     alert(value)
    // });
</script>
```

Sinatra Server:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/websocketio'

set :port, 5005
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
set :public_folder, "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/views"
set :websocketio, port: 9000
enable :sessions


get '/list' do
  "Hello world!"
end

get '/' do
  erb :index, layout: :layout
end
```

JavaScript side cannot connect:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Sinatra::WebSocketIO` [only starts up once an EventMachine reactor is running](https://github.com/shokai/sinatra-websocketio/blob/8280860ef79cf6ebe6a151702c6ce085f7002aa8/lib/sinatra-websocketio/websocketio.rb#L13-L15).  This is the case when running a EventMachine-based Rack server (such as [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/)).  Switching the Rack server to Thin starts up the WebSocketIO server just fine.

If switching to Thin is not an option, you could also start the EventMachine reactor inside of your `config.ru`:

```
require_relative "./server"  # assuming your server code is in `./server.rb`

run Sinatra::Application

# EventMachine.run blocks the active thread, therefore it's started in a separate one
Thread.new { EventMachine.run }
```

The Rack server can then be started using `bundle exec rackup -p 5005`